# Height of one div is affecting position of another

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small application and I got stuck as soon as I started. I wrote some HTML and CSS, but height of one div is affecting the position of another div.

Here is my HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header></header>
   <div id="container">

       <div class="container1">
           <div class="title">Title 1</div>
           <ul class="action">
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
           </ul>
       </div>


        <div class="container2">
            <div class="title">  Title 2  </div>
            <ul class="list">Some random text</ul>
            <ul class="options">
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
                <li>Option 4</li>
                <li>Option 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: dimgray;
}

ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.container1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.container2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.title{
    width: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}


ul.list{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 300px;
}

ul.options li{
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do53tmup/)

I can use positioning and achieve what I want as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445861/height-of-one-div-moving-another-for-unknown-reason) SO post.

But if anyone can please explain me why changing the height of container2 in my markup is affecting the position of container1, that will be a huge help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juts give `vertical-align: top;` to `div.container1`

Because both container are `display: inline-block;` by default they are `vertical-align:baseline`.

```
div.container1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do53tmup/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, more so because of the reason you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
div.container1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```